# creating array of directories in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hello here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have this code to scan specific directory and store all sub-directories within array. But when I output it with foreach, only one value is outputted.My code:

```
foreach(glob($directories.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $sloz) {
$dirname = array (basename($sloz)); }

<?php foreach ($dirname as $slozka) {
    echo <<<dir
$("a[rel='$slozka']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"}).;
dir;
} ?>
<?php echo '}'.PHP_EOL ?>
```

The output is always just one line with sub-directory

Any ideas?

Comment: You are reassigning `$dirname` each time you iterate. You need to use `$dirname[]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop appears incorrect:

```
foreach(glob($directories.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $sloz) {
    $dirname = array (basename($sloz));
}
```

I assume you are trying to build an array of matches. But in this loop you are just assigning the value to variable `$dirname` in each case.

You are then trying to iterate over a non-iterable value, which triggers a `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...`, although I assume you do not have warnings enabled since you did not mention this.

Try the following:

```
$dirname = [];

foreach (glob($directories.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $sloz) {
    $dirname[] = basename($sloz);
}
```

Then you can `foreach` over your array of `$dirname` values.

Comment: Oh yeah thats working when i remowe that "array" before (basename($sloz)). Im just PHP newbie so many thanks!! :)

Comment: No problem @Houdasek - glad to help :)